# Facebook login -Python 3 Requests module

Tags: python-3.x, web-applications, python-requests

Why does this script still bring me to the main page (not logged in)? 
*Imagine the email and pass were good*

```
import requests
par = {'email':'addddd','Pass':'ggdddssd'}
r = requests.post('https://www.facebook.com',data=par)
print (r.text)
```

or even trying trying to search with the search bar on youtube:

```
<input id="masthead-search-term" name="search_query" value="" type="text" tabindex="1"title="Rechercher">

import requests
par = {'search_query':'good_songs_on_youtube'}
r = requests.post('https://www.youtube.com',data=par)
print (r.text)
```

doesn't make any search... any ideas why?

Comment: Show us your print output please

Comment: @xsquared it is just the same content than the original https://www.facebook.com request (identical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to login like this for two reasons:

1. When you post an HTML form - you should use the form's "action" as the url. For example:

---

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1' #the form's action url
par = {"email": "********", "password": "********"} # the forms parameters
r = requests.post(url, data=par)
print (r.content) # you can't use r.text because of encoding
```

---

2. In your case, this is also not good enough cause FB requires cookies, you might be able to program your way out of it, but it won't be easy/straight-forward.

So, how *can* you login (programmatically) to FB and post queries ?
You can install and use [their SDK](http://%20%20%20%20url%20=%20'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1'), and there are also open source projects such as [this one](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) that uses FB API and supports oauth as well.

You will have to go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and get your API token in order to use it with the oauth authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For youtube, you should use "GET" request instead of post to get the valid response. I've given a demo using your search query "good_songs" and showed how to fetch the results:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='
search = 'good_songs'

response = requests.get(url + search).text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
for item in tree.xpath("//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' yt-uix-tile-link ')]/text()"):
    print (item)
```